# Difference between writing C# code in Html page(inline) and aspx.cs (code behind)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Script does not work when i remove **language="C#"** and add **type="text/C#"** in its tag.
What is the difference between both  of them.

Another Question is why can't i access html Controls while writing code in **aspx.cs** file, what is the difference between both styles of writing C#

and how can i access html controls so easily if i am writing code in **aspx.cs file** ,  like in the following event function and what is the object for source in its parameters

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script language="C#" runat="server">
  void Submit_bttn1(object Source,EventArgs e)
  {
    SpanMsg.InnerHtml= "your Suggestions are  "+Textarea1.Value;
  }  
 </script>
</head>



<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<p>
                               Page 2
</p>
    <div>
     <textarea id="Textarea1" cols="15" rows="5" runat="server"></textarea>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" runat="server" onserverclick="Submit_bttn1" />
     <span id="SpanMsg" runat="server"></span>
    </div>

      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>
     <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
   </p>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

There must be some pros and cons of writing C# code in both styles so what would be the scenerio for writing C# code in html page . Thanks

Comment: usually from my experience if you are wanting to write client side scripting and or trigger events on the client vs the server side you you would write code in the markup I would guess that you are trying to execute / invoke some method prior to doing a PostBack look at how to use `Update Panel` as well perhaps this can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using inline code:

PROS:

1. Easy to create
2. Easy to write
3. Easy deployment
4. etc.

CONS:

1. Spaghetti code
2. Limited intelissense
3. Hard to debug
4. etc.

Using code behind:

PROS:

1. Separation of concerns (if created well)
2. Compile time warnings (VS)
3. Better debugging
4. Code reuse etc..

CONS:

1. It can be a tangled mess if app isnot properly designed.
2. Less control in html
3. Required VS.NET etc.

I prefer code behind because of the seperation of UI and business logic. But from time to time I am having a vacation in inline when I am creating a web part page in sharepoint.

Answer (score 1):

from my side there is no pros and cons.

before .net 2.0 
there is code like this the html and c# was in one page but the fell the need of code separation.
so in 2.0 the separate the code and html for separation of concern .

so now we have aspx.cs page and aspx page in  asp.net
aspx.cs is for the c# code and aspx is for html

we can write c# in aspx but when the code will become to large then developer will confused

that's it thanks

:D

Comment: So when there is a ease of writing separate code there is no need to write code in script ...I got your point

Comment: now a days mostly people follow the MVC for separation of concerns

Answer (score 0):

The .aspx page contains HTML and client side code (JavaScript). The code behind files contain server side logic. It's important to make the distinction.

The only reason it's handy to embed the C# on the .aspx page is to show quick examples of code.

Answer (score 0):

I just followed a [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd902097%28v=office.12%29.aspx) on how to upload a file to a SharePoint library (2007). The c# sample code was written in the HTML markup.  I wondered why and landed here. I assume the reason is because it is easier access to SharePoint (or maybe the only way?). My two 2 cents for what it's worth.